# Check in Components with Core Service (Tridion 2013 SP1) is not working

Tags: 2013, core-service

We had a Core Service script running that left thousands of Components checked out.

I would like to fix this with another script based on Robert's example (http://www.curlette.com/?p=1095). I don't see errors but nothing seems to happen. 
Is there something else I can try?

**Update**

My simple script (used with LINQPad)

```
RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData filter = new RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData();  
XElement checkedOutItemsXml =Tridion.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);  
checkedOutItemsXml.Nodes().Count().Dump();  
ReadOptions ro = new ReadOptions();  
ro.LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded;  

foreach (XElement tridionItem in checkedOutItemsXml.Nodes())  
{  
    if (tridionItem.Attribute("Type").Value == "16" || tridionItem.Attribute("Type").Value == "64")  
    {  
        VersionedItemData response = Tridion.CheckIn(tridionItem.Attribute("ID").Value, ro);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you have Workflow enabled on the system? If so, then maybe they're now in Workflow process. You could try the `client.UndoCheckOut()` method. Are you running the new script as an admin user? Can you 'manually' undo the checkout (or check-in) on these items successfully?

Comment: "_nothing seems to happen_" ... does the additional logging that I presume you've added to give you more information ... log?

Comment: Under what credentials is the Core Service script run? Since you have to be an Administrator to be able to override a checkout (and I suggest to use the `UndoCheckOut` instead indeed).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm running the script as Administrator. Also we don't have a workflow enabled. 
UndoCheckout is not working and i think the effect will be that the changes done by the previous script will be gone.
I can check Components in manually.

Comment: Additionally - CheckinAsync isn't even working. The problem is that we have to update alot of components (thousands of them) and Checkin does not give any error (indeed being an Admin it should not), but checkin does NOT actually checks-in.. Also consider that the components are big and until the last components gets checked in, another is fired for checkin. so not sure if that is not letting the components get checked in.

Comment: Why don't you write the script to just check-in one component. Once you're happy that is working then expand it to iterate over the whole collection of components - possibly with a delay between each component, if needed.
Maybe you could post your code too so we can check that all looks okay.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 
Actually i was looking into the issue Vikas has with his script.I started simple (see code snippet i've added above)

Comment: If your previous script didn't check in changes, then indeed you should use `Checkin` rather than `UndoCheckOut`. Or perhaps you use  `UndoCheckOut` and fix that previous script to do a correct job and run it again ;o). Is your update additional info to the question or a solution? In case of the latter, please self-answer and accept that answer.

Comment: You really need to **edit** your question and provide more details, you seem to be using the `ICoreService2011.CheckIn` method, and I wonder why you are not using the more current `ICoreService2013.CheckIn` method which has additional parameters. If you mention it doesn't do anything, then something else is happening and you need to debug your script.See the API guide, this method should check-in the item. This means that the editable version is turned into the new current version and the lock on the item is removed. So in short it should do the job, but use the right parameters and endpoint.

Comment: @MinkoScheltinga - I see that you're using Tridion 2013. Have you tried installing hotfix CM_2013.1.0.88013? That addresses a bug in 2013 & 2013 SP1 where administrators could no longer see items checked out by other users.

Answer (score 3):

Bart was right, we used `ICoreService2011.CheckIn`. With `ICoreService2013.CheckIn` the script from Vikas worked fine.
Will update the Linqpad driver, to avoid these kind of questions in the future...

Thanks!